# Simplify a logic expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm studying to my exam and I have some doubts.

The expression:
$$
         \lnot \lnot P \land \lnot(\lnot\lnot Q \lor\lnot P)
$$

The result:
$$
         P \land \lnot Q
$$

The objective is to simplify.

I reach to 
$$
         P \land \lnot Q \land P
$$
and then I don't know what to do.

Could I use the idempotence property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* commute and associate: $P\wedge \neg Q\wedge P = (P\wedge P)\wedge \neg Q$.

Now, what is $(P\wedge P) = \underline{\qquad}$?

Comment: It's P thanks :-)